# Cordova inappbrowser - Read (httponly) SESSION cookie

Tags: cordova, cookies, cordova-plugins

I am working with a platform that (at the moment) does not really support authentification for native apps and I was told by the platform supplier to "just open a webview and use the session cookie for authenticating ajax requests".

So I am using the inappbrowser plugin to open the authentification page of the platform and letting the platform handle the sign in flow (web-based). After that, I need to access the Session cookie, which is httponly so using executeScript to read the cookies doesn't work.

Is there any way to access the cookies stored by inappbrowser directly? From Cordova. I need the credentials in Cordova to be able to call a custom swift extension with them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.